# Relationship between degrees of freedom and heat capacity and absolute zero?

Tags: thermodynamics

The Wikipedia article on [heat capacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Degrees_of_freedom) indicates that there is a relationship between the number of degrees of freedom and the heat capacity. I understand this in terms of the equipartition theorem but how I can't understand how this can be used to explain that heat capacity must go to zero as absolute temperature goes to zero (since here equipartition theorem will not hold). So please can someone intuitively explain this to me?

Comment: It's true that the equipartition theorem predictions relating to heat capacity fail in the $T\to 0$ limit. You instead need a quantum-based model such as that of [Einstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_solid) or [Debye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model).

Comment: @lemon Hi, thanks I understand this. I am just really confused about the physical reasoning why the heat capacity is zero at $T=0$ and not at other temperatures.

Answer (score 3):

The heat capacity depends on how many degrees of freedom can be excited. In QM to excite a degree of freedom one needs to at least excite one quanta so the typical temperature when a degree of freedom comes into play is $T_t = (E_1-E_0)/k_b$. Here a figure as an example for a diatomic gas
[image]

You can see that when T reaches $T_\text{rot}$ and $T_\text{vib}$ C_\text{V} increases by $k_b$ respectively. For a gas $C_V$ does not go to zero as $T\rightarrow\infty$. The reason is the number of states at zero excitation energy. For a gas there are relatively many states at zero excitation energy because every atom can move with arbitrarely small kinetic energy in every direction. For a solid there are very few states at zero excitation because only the acoustic phonon branches at $k\rightarrow 0$ can be excited.