# What is the relation between the degree of freedom of a molecule and the heat capacity?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm confused. How can a change in the degree of freedom of a molecule can change the heat capacity?

Comment: If the degrees of freedom change, then it is a different molecule. But, more internal degrees of freedom means there are more ways for the molecule to absorb energy through vibrational modes, since there are more of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relationship between degrees of freedom and heat capacity and absolute zero?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249811/relationship-between-degrees-of-freedom-and-heat-capacity-and-absolute-zero)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal answer is known as the *Equipartition Theorem*, which states that, at thermal equilibrium, any degree of freedom that appears quadratically in the expression of the system's energy has an average energy of $\frac{1}{2}k_B T$. This means that any degree of freedom that appears quadratically in the energy gives the system an additional heat capacity of $\frac{\partial E}{\partial T}=\frac{1}{2}k_B$. Proofs of this can be found in many places, including Wikipedia and most textbooks.

Intuitively, this makes sense. Degrees of freedom are essentially different ways to store energy (e.g. as translational kinetic energy, rotational kinetic energy, elastic potential energy, magnetic energy, etc.). At equilibrium, it would be reasonable to expect that the energy of the system is equally distributed among the possible ways to store it. As such, the more ways a system can store energy, the less its  particles' kinetic energy will rise when you inject more energy into the system (because that energy is more spread out over the non-kinetic degrees of freedom). As such, more degrees of freedom means less temperature change for a given energy change, which means more heat capacity.

Comment: Can a degree of freedom appear non-quadratically in the energy? Is there a more general theorem that takes into account also non-quadratic terms?

Answer (score 0):

Thermal systems interact a lot internally.  Because of this, they reach "equipartition" - every mode contains the same average energy, $1/2 kT$.

If you have more modes, the system contains more energy at a given temperature.  That means that it'll absorb more energy to *raise* it's temperature.  Hence a larger heat capacity that a system with a small number of modes.

Molecules with one degree of freedom will absorb $1/2 k \Delta T$ to increase the temperature by $\Delta T$, but ones with three times as many modes will absorb three times as much energy:  $3/2 \Delta T$.